# Adding Directories to Xcode custom project template creates weird recursion

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6

I am trying to create an Xcode project template that will include a directory filled with classe files using the following in the .plist for the template :

```
<key>Definitions</key>
<dict>
    <key>Classes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Path</key>
        <string>Classes</string>
    </dict>
</dict>

<key>Nodes</key>
<array>
    <string>Classes</string>
</array>
```

This almost works but the last file in Classes always becomes a reference folder to the Classes file creating a weird recursion.

As an example, let's say Classes has 3 files, a.h, b.h and c.h.  The resulting project will have a file structure that looks like this :

```
project
+-Classes
  +-a.h
  +-b.h
  +-c.h //This is not a proper .h file, it is a file reference
    +-a.h
    +-b.h
    +-c.h //This is the actual .h file
```

Is there a clean way to have the project template copy all files from a directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research, it seems that this is a bug with Xcode's template system.  There doesn't seem to be a way to copy directories that contain other files without creating this problem (at least at the time of writing this answer).

The only alternative I was able to find was to manually specify each file inside a directory in the project template, specifying the file's group to match the folder structure.

```
<key>Definitions</key>
<dict>
    <key>Classes/a.h</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Group</key>
        <array>
            <string>Classes</string>
        </array>
        <key>Path</key>
        <string>Classes/a.h</string>
    </dict>
    <!--Repeat for b and c-->
</dict>

<key>Nodes</key>
<array>
    <string>Classes/a.h</string>
    <!--Repeat for b and c-->
</array>
```